# Why does subscribing to RSocket connectionStatus() on a connected socket result in two callback calls?

Tags: rsocket, rsocket-js

```
socket.connectionStatus().subscribe((status) => console.log("Connection status changed: ", status));
```

results in:

```
Connection status changed: Object { kind: "CONNECTED" }
Connection status changed: Object { kind: "CONNECTED" }
```

The documentation of `connectionStatus()` states:

> Returns a Flowable that immediately publishes the current connection
> * status and thereafter updates as it changes. [...]

Comment: This looks like a bug, consider creating a repro and filing with rsocket-js project.